# Passing only one generic type which defines the other generics

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I have the following method:

```cs
public void SomeMethod<TParser, T1, T2> () where TParser : IParser<T1, T2>, new() 
{
   ...
}
```

and an `IParser<T1, T2>` interface and a class which implements it:

```cs
public interface IParser<T1, T2>
{
   ...
}

public class Parser : IParser<string, int>
{
   ...
}
```

Now my questions is would it be possible to only pass `TParser` to the method, since there is a constraint set which kinda defines `T1` and `T2`. So would it be possible to do something like the following:

```cs
SomeMethod<Parser>();
```

I would guess it isn't possible, but would there be something similar?

Comment: No, unfortunately, this is not possible and it's a common pain in C#.

Comment: Well that is a real shame ... Do you know if there are any plans for it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define a non-generic version of your interface. And derive your generic interface from it and use non-generic version as a constraint. And if you have parameters of type  `T1` and `T2` this won't be useful.

```
internal interface IParser
{
... // if you can define any. or it can be empty also
}

public interface IParser<T1, T2> : IParser
{
   ...
}
```

And change your method signature to this :

```
public void SomeMethod<TParser> () where TParser : IParser new() 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Well it was only a simplified version of my actual problem, I do need the actual `T1` and `T2` types in the method for further casting and processing. Thanks for the answer anyway!